# bigfoot.js and numbers with 2 characters

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use bigfoot.js on my web site.
It works but only for the 9 first footnote.

the original plugin ask for this structure:

```
<p>
<sup id="fnref:1">
    <a href="#fn:1" rel="footnote">1</a>
</sup>
</p>
```

On my website using the CMS SPIP, my footnote are like this:

```
<span class="spip_note_ref">
<a href="#nb3" class="spip_note" rel="footnote" title="mytitle(...)" id="nh3">3</a>
</span>
```

So i use a plugin SPIP who add this script to adapt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
(function($) {
var bigfoot_init = function() {
    jQuery.bigfoot({
        anchorPattern: /(nb\dfootnote|appendix)/gi,
        anchorParentTagname: "span",
        footnoteParentClass: "spip_note_ref",
        footnoteTagname: "div"
    });
    jQuery('div.notes').hide();
};
$(function(){
    bigfoot_init();
    onAjaxLoad(bigfoot_init);
});
})(jQuery);
/* ]]> */</script>
```

Did you see any reason why the code work for footnote from 1 to 9 but doesnt work after.

You can see exemple online here:
http://test.cas-p.net/spip.php?article1

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHould replace

```
/(nb\dfootnote|appendix)/gi
```

by

```
/(nb(\d)+(footnote|appendix))/gi
```

And it worksgreat